# can not conect to meteor from localhost:3000/192.168.1.104:3000

Tags: meteor, localhost, virtualbox

I have installed SentOS7 to my Virtual Machine.  And also I
installed meteor, but I can not open in web browser my application. Can you help me to solve this issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3sZo8Pk

Answer (score 0):

Run Your app binded to `192.168.1.104:3000` or `0.0.0.0:3000`, not `localhost:3000`.

If You run app in VM, addr must be visible to other machines. `127.0.0.1` is local address. This addr is never visible to other machines.

Comment: this is a VM networking problem, not Meteor. What do you use? KVM, VirtualBox? how is the networking setup? NAT, bridge?